# Setting a Default value in XAML in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set a default value for a combobox. I have scripts that create the code tables, so writing the code like this is not an option:

```
<StackPanel>
<ComboBox SelectedValue="CA">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA">California</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Instead I have some code in the XAML:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" Name="PersonStackPanel" Height="60">
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Normal" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Person</Label>
            <ComboBox Name="PersonComboBox"  Width="312" Props.CodeProvider="MASTCODE.TYPE.ARRA" DisplayMemberPath="NAME" Tag="AA" IsSelected="True" SelectedValuePath="CODE" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PERSON}"/>
 <StackPanel>
```

i thought Tag="AA" IsSelected="True" would work but it is not.

Comment: Why do you use Tag instead of SelectedValue in your seond code example?

Comment: Is Person stored in a ViewModel?

Comment: @RandRandom I thought that it would take the tag from the scripts.

Comment: @BobbyRicky Tag does nothing. Tag is just a simple object that is mostly used as a garbage bin for everything you want to associate with a control, it has no further purpose and is there for atleast the last 100years :D. If you want to have a default value selected you have to either say SelectedValue="CA" (where the Value of a ComboBoxItem must fit this value) - SelectedIndex=0 (where the index of a ComboBoxItem must fit this value) - or the best of them all you say SelectedItem=SomeCLRobject (where the item of a ComboBoxItem must fit this value) `BUT` you should really look into ItemsSource

Answer (score 19):

Any value that is displayed in a combobox has to be present as a selection.

Try:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Edit: added quotations

Comment: Caution: This changes value shown in the combo box, but doesn't change the underlying bound value until the user actually changes the selection. So it can be extremely dangerous in terms of triggering unexpected/surprising behaviour.

Comment: Doesn't display the first value.

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
SelectedValuePath="CODE"
```

so in this case try to set **SelectedValue** instead of **SelectedItem**

Answer (score 1):

Set Person to appropriate value in your ViewModel (perhaps the constructor if you want default item).

```
Person = //some object
```

and change Binding to

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PERSON, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I think this will do:

```
    <ComboBox Name="PersonComboBox"  Width="312" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PERSON}" SelectedIndex="0" >
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="AA">Adam</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

I think what I was confused about was, since I have a script creating the combobox item, I don't need to create it in the XAML. But as long as i can save that data to the "Person" column I am good with it.